# Artisan command gives error 'Object of class Closure could not be converted to string'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'd like to use `Schedule` in Laravel on Mac. This is my crod file:

`SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
* * * * * php /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxxy/xxyyy/artisan schedule:run >> $run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

This is Kernel.php

```
namespace App\Console;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
protected $commands = [
     //Commands\Inspire::class,
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{   
    $schedule->command(function () {
        dispatch(new \App\Jobs\sendPush);
    })->everyMinute();        
}
}
```

Anything I type into the terminal with artisan gives this error :

> [ErrorException] Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Have you any idea how to make Artisan work?

sendPush.php

```
class sendPush extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;
public function __construct()
{
    //
}
public function handle(MessageController $MessageController)
{
    $MessageController->sendDefault();
}
```

Comment: Can you please give more detailed error log, and the code of your \App\Jobs\SendPush? - You can find the error log file on storage/logs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used these before, but a quick skim of the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling) seems to highlight your problem:

> You may define all of your scheduled tasks in the schedule method of the App\Console\Kernel class. To get started, let's look at an example of scheduling a task. In this example, we will schedule a Closure to be called every day at midnight. Within the Closure we will execute a database query to clear a table:

and

> In addition to scheduling Closure calls, you may also schedule Artisan commands and operating system commands. For example, you may use the command method to schedule an Artisan command using either the command's name or class:

It seems instead of using the `command` method you need to use the `call` method as you are passing in a `Closure` and not a commands name or class.

So I believe you simply need to update your code to the below:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {   
    $schedule->call(function () {
        dispatch(new \App\Jobs\sendPush);
    })->everyMinute();        
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it don't gives error it says `Running scheduled command: Closure` so I think it's running now I just don't get the push message I should but it's a start thanks again!

Comment: @J.Doe - great news, I would advise reading the doc pages carefully in future. I've never used this before but it was a quick find. If it has served you well please upvote and accept this answer so the question will be closed off :-)